# Moving data from one sheet to another via a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I've searched the existing questions and found similar questions and answers but none that meet my requirements.

I have a spreadsheet where I wish to be able to click on links in one spreadsheet to take you to the second, placing the value in the cell clicked into a field in the second.

For example, the first sheet in column A will contain the units `IT`, `Finance`, and `Networks`

Click on any of these fields should take the user to the second sheet called "Sub Unit" placing the value of the cell in A1 where I can then write if statements to populate the sub unit list, for example clicking on `IT` would put `IT` in cell A1 and then via if statements in A3-A5 would make those as

```
Security, Support, Development
```

Then I would reuse similar VB code so that if someone clicks on a sub unit name, it takes them to a third sheet that will show the details for the sub unit.

Hope that makes sense,

I'm very new to VBA a so please indicate where I should place any code (e.g. in the tab, right click, view code, or in some different place)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce to Copy cell value from sheet to another using the `Hyperlink`. But I can suggest you how to Copy cell value to another sheet using VBA(Macro) on Mouse click.

Comment: That may work if you could post an example ill try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Sheet 1 press `ALT+F11` to get the VB editor. Copy & Paste this code as standard module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox "Range " & Target.Address & " was double clicked"
 On Error Resume Next
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Application.Selection
    Range("A80").Copy Sheet2.Range("A80")
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A80"), True
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Write some data in Cell `A80` & double click 
  the cell.
- You get the Message box to confirm which cell 
  has been clicked.
- Press `OK` button.
- Excel will `Copy & Paste` the content 
  of `A80` & place the cell pointer to 
  Cell `A80` of Sheet 2.

**N.B.**

- Adjust the cell references & Sheet 
  name in code as needed.
- You may refer Range of cells to `Copy & 
  Paste`.
- To do so edit this line,,
- `Range("A80:A85").Copy Sheet2.Range("A80")`

Comment: That works great but is there a way to stop the popup confirming the cell clicked and just have it go straight to the sheet2. Ignore this, worked it out :)

Comment: Yes it's possible,, either put apostrophe`'` symbol at the beginning of this `MsgBox "Range " & Target.Address & " was double clicked"` or delete this line. Excel will read the next command line.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I've got it all working as above, but would like rather than copying a range, e.g. A80:A85 into A80, instead to copy the single cell double clicked into A80, but that cell to be any cell in a particular range. i.e. I put my values into A1 A2 A3 on sheet 1 for the person to double click on, and then only the value they double click is moved into A1 on sheet2

Comment: If you wanna to copy any specific one then need to be mentioned in the command line, Excel literally reads the command to act on ! Since you are looking for a Hyperlink type of effect that's Y the Mouse Click event has been used otherwise the selected Cell or Range can be copied also.!! ☺

Comment: Thanks, i went with this in the end 'Private Sub >Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

 On Error Resume Next
    >Dim xRg As Range
    >Set xRg = Application.Selection
    
   > If Target.Address = "$A$80" Then
    >Range("A80").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    >ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$79" Then
    Range("A79").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Else
    >Exit Sub
    >End If
    >Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), True
    >Range("B1").Value = Target
>End Sub'

Comment: @DavidGardiner,, if it's working in the way you like then looking great. I've posted my solution on the basis of the OP and it's working. Modifications are always possible. If you found that my solution has helped you to improvise the code then you may Accept it as answer or vote. ☺

Comment: Glad to help you @DavidGardiner,, keep asking ☺